# static_transform_publisher negative average delay

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use static_transform_publisher to provide a static transform, the average delay is negative. My questions are: 1) Is this a problem? 2) If so, is there a reason it's doing this, and how do I fix it?

For example, when I run:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /frame1 /frame2 100
```

tf_monitor shows:

```
RESULTS: for /frame1 to /frame2
Chain is: /frame1 -> /frame2
Net delay     avg = -0.0473741: max = 0.000169573

Frames:
Frame: /frame2 published by /static_transform_publisher_1301872460950178911 Average Delay: -0.0997857 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: /static_transform_publisher_1301872460950178911 10.3418 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0997857 Max Delay: 0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9629/static_transform_publisher-negative-average-delay/) by [Corey Montella](https://answers.ros.org/users/45/corey-montella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Negative average delay comes from the transform being timestamped in the future when sent or by network delays when running in simulation.

In simulation time is sent over the /clock topic and may arrive after transforms sent from a different node with the same time.

A few nodes stamp data in the future, most noteably AMCL. This is valid for AMCL and other similar nodes publishing a small correction transform which is expected to remain approximately static and never have inherent velocity. The value is that AMCL can update at a slow rate but does not prevent transforms through it's correction to be used at a high rate.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3